# How to solve this error with modal using bootstrap 5

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I'm using react 6 and bootstrap 5. The tutorial adds window but i think I'm getting the error based on Modal.

***Im getting this error :***

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.
> at Checkout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5223:87)
> at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:49760:5)
> at main
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at FrontendLayout Checkout.js:135 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Modal')
> at Checkout.js:135:1

This is the code

```js
 var myModal = new window.bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('payOnlineModal'));
                                myModal.show();
```

```html
  <div class="modal fade" id="payOnlineModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Online Payment Mode</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <hr />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var myModal =  window.bootstrap?.Modal(document.getElementById('payOnlineModal'));
                                myModal?.show();
```

I do not know why you use the new keyword. But with this kind of error, in normal cases we can use optional chaining (.?)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I just added that and I got this message " constructors in/after an Optional Chain are not allowed (135:65) "   . I hope that someone can help me to re-write that in another way to fix the bug , help please.